# Django Parallel Processing

Tags: python, django, parallel-processing, multitasking

I have a simple Django project.

Each time a user hits the homepage,some operations are performed based on which,view is generated. Now the problem is that when a user hits the homepage ,sometimes the operations take a long time based on network connectivity. If in the meantime, a new user hits the homepage,he has to wait for the request from the previous user to get serviced before the page gets rendered.

I found Celery is used for task scheduling and queuing . But I wonder if Celery is what i need.I need each user to have his request be processed independently and not queued.

My project is a single app project and will receive a maximum of 100 users a time.

Thanks.

Comment: What operations are you performing? Synchronous operations will never work on a web application (what do you intend to do with 1^n users? or even if all 100 users are doing the same thing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the long process needs to be done in order to serve the request and generate the proper response then you cannot use Celery.

The debug web-server that is shipped with Django is a multi-threaded-single-process server, but is really very limited [and should not be used in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port).

If you use gunicorn or other wsgi servers you can run your application in multiple processes but you will hit the limit quickly if you're doing heavy processing.

The solution would be in my opinion is to either change the way you're processing stuff, either prepare ahead or serve the request and do the processing in the background, you can show the user a `Please wait...` message, here you can use Celery to do the processing.

The other solution would be to use event-based web-server like [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/) or [cyclone](http://cyclone.io) or [others](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Helped me move int he right direction. Will deploy it in apache in production.